# Blender UV bake problem!

Tags: uv, texture-baking, baking, uv-image-editor

Hello I have been using blender for some time now but have never encountered this before, for some reason my UV's are not baking to the full extent of my islands. [image: UV's]

I could just start a fresh and re-import my model, re-do my UV's etc and I'm guessing that would probably fix it but I feel it may be unnecessary work, I feel like I may have accidentally clicked on an option somewhere and can't for the life of me figure out what it is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: that sure looks like it has something to do with a subdivision surface modifier. Check if "subdivide UVs" is checked on it.

Comment: Perfect!!!!! I knew something was going on just couldn't put my finger on it, had a subdivision modifier on! somehow I managed to add it without realizing, the model is not meant to have any modifier's on what so ever, cheers buddy!! saved me a few hours of pulling my hair out. =)